# How to leave NULL data in the database.with SELECT statement?

Tags: php, sql, database, select, null

My users can post a picture and message to my php database. But I want them to be able to leave either one blank. The problem is when I call from the database I have either a broken picture logo or empty text box displayed if they leave one blank.

I need my SELECT statement to not collect any column in the row with NULL in it, so it won't be displayed in the feed.

All the other posts I've read find a NULL entry and skip the entire row.

This is not code but may give an idea what I want it to do:

$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM user_posts SELECT '***all row entries except NULL's***';") ;

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM user_posts ORDER BY post_id DESC;") ;
                    
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {


                              echo "<div class='Timg_div'>";



                            if (is_null (post_message)) {

                                echo "<textarea class='title_post' placeholder='No Title Here'>".$row['post_message']. "</textarea>";
                                }
                        else    {
                            
                                echo "<textarea class='title_post' placeholder='No Title Here' style='display: none;'>".$row['post_title']. "</textarea>";
                                }       
                           
                            if (is_null (post_image)) {

                               echo "<img src='uploads/".$row['post_image']."' class='image_feed' >";

                                }
                        else    {

                               echo "<img src='uploads/".$row['post_image']."' class='image_feed' style='display: none'>";
                                }   

                                echo "</div>";
                                }
```

Comment: You can't return different columns on different rows. You should fix the code that displays the results so it checks for `null` and doesn't display that field.

Comment: Your other option is better definition of the database schema itself such that column defaults don't leave you with null values, say a default picture or empty string instead.

Comment: Hi Barmar, maybe I din't explain it properly. I'm only looking to return one row. But I want to omit any columns that don't have any data in it so the user has the choice to upload a picture without a message or a message without a picture. My code does try to leave null behind but it wasn't working with IF statement or Case statements so I've taken to trying it with the SELECT statement. I will edit my OP to show the code I tried.

Comment: Hi Parttimeturtle, I have already achieved your suggestion and it looks a bit sloppy to me which is why I'm trying to find a cleaner option. Thanks.

Comment: Quick thought experiment: if you manage to achieve what you want, how will you write your display code so that it knows to write an `img` tag if there's an image, and not if there isn't? Will that look different to writing one if it has a value, and not if it has a NULL?

Comment: Hi IMSoP, I've updated my OP, the last IF ELSE statement deals with the image and is set to not display anything if NULL is returned. Instead of returning a row I would set it to return an image from my folder. Problem is I can't get the if statements to do their job which is why I moved to trying to use the SELECT statement. If you can solve the problem from my code outputs I would take that as a win. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I can't find a way for the SELECT statement to do what I want but I have made the echo code do it with CASE statement's.

Only downside is if the user enters nothing into any fields then a small 'DIV' area is added to the page, which I can live with or maybe prevent NULL uploads from the SUBMIT button somehow.

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "
SELECT               post_image
FROM                 user_posts
ORDER BY             post_id DESC
;"
);

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                            echo "<div class='Timg_div'>";

                    switch ($row['post_image'] != '' ) {
                    case "IS NOT NULL" :
                            
                            echo "<img src='uploads/".$row['post_image']."' class='image_feed' >";

                    break;  

                    case ""  :
                            echo "";
                                }   

                                  echo "</div>";
                            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly check for `null`s using the `is` operator:

```sql
SELECT   *
FROM     user_posts 
WHERE    post_image IS NOT NULL AND post_message IS NOT NULL -- here
ORDER BY post_id DESC
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying but this is something I've already tried. The problem here for example is that it detects a NULL in the 'post_message' column and refuses to return anything in the entire row, including the 'post_image'. I want it return any information that HAS been filled in by the user and only omit the NULL fields. Thanks.